# I want to use phonetic package in TeXstudio!

Tags: errors, packages, miktex

I'm using TeXstudio and MiKTeX, and I want to use `phonetic` package. However, it doesn't work. How can I use this package?

I already installed phonetic package from MiKTeX Package Manager:

[image]

I want to use `$\rc{v}$`

This is the related link: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/phonetic.

Comment: Welcome, the error message indicates that the package isn t installed, yet you claim you did install the package. One thing you can do is download the `sty` file directly from CTAN and put it in your working project directory.

Comment: update the file name database (FNDB). Run MikTeX Settings. On the General tab under maintenance, click Refresh FNDB.

Comment: Unless you have legacy code which requires the package, I don't recommend the `phonetic` package; it's quite limited. See [How to use phonetic IPA characters in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/36542) for other options.